# Why does a sub-class call super() by default?

Tags: java, oop, constructor, subclass

This question has been bugging me for a while now, and I haven't found a good answer (other than "that's just how it is").

Let me give some background code, to show what I'm talking about.

```
class Note {
    private final String name = "Note";

    public Note() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    // ...
}

class Todo extends Note {
    private final String name = "Todo";

    public Todo() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    // ...
}

// ...
Note note = new Todo(); // case 1
Todo todo = new Todo(); // case 2
```

So how come both case 1 and case 2 print out:

```
Note
Todo
```

This makes no sense, since `Todo()` (constructor) does not call `super()` (at least not visibly). Why would the sub-class have to call the parents default constructor, why not just require any sub-class to implement a constructor?

I read a couple [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370520/subclass-constructors-why-must-the-default-constructor-exist-for-subclass-cons) related to this, but none answer *why*.

**Edit:**
I guess my example was kind of poor, but It's actually a derivative from a Java 7 Certification question.. From the collective of answers I now understand *why*. Let me provide a better example:

```
public Note {
    private String description;

    public Note() {
        description = "I'm a Note";
    }

    public Note( String description ) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    // getters/setters/etc.
}

public Todo extends Note {
    // field vars..

    public Todo() {
        // empty constructor
    }

    // getters/setters/etc..
}
```

So now this makes more sense, since when `Todo` is created, if `super()` was not inserted behind the covers, the `Note` aspect of the `Todo` would not be initialized. Which would be pointless to have a sub-class in that case. Thanks all!

Comment: For me it prints 
`Note
Todo
Note
Todo` which makes sense because you are creating a `Note` and a `ToDo` in both cases in that order.

Comment: I did mention that that was the output, but the question is: why call the default constructor of the parent class by default.

Comment: Because every object must be constructed! (like [Every Sperm is Sacred](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Every_Sperm_Is_Sacred))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question can be separated into two parts.

1. Why does any constructor of the superclass have to be called? This is easy: the constructor is responsible for setting up the state of the object, and since there can be state in the superclass not visible to the subclass code (i.e. `private` fields), this can only be dealt with by calling a constructor of the superclass.
2. Why don't you have to call `super()` explicitly? This is just a fairly arbitrary design decision made in Java to make code look simpler. It ties in nicely with the concept of a `default constructor` (i.e. the implied no-arg constructor that exists in classes that don't have an explicit constructor defined), although as can be seen in your example, it also works when you have a no-arg constructor explicitly defined in the superclass.

Answer (score 7):

The subclass constructor has to call *some* constructor.  If you haven't told it which to use, it will use the default constructor.

The alternative is having variables in the superclass be completely uninitialized and yet accessible by the subclass and/or its methods, which would be *spectacularly* bad.

The decision to silently call the default superclass constructor, rather than e.g. fail to compile, is debatable, though, but I suspect it's tied to the existence of a "default constructor" in the first place.

FYI, your question also suggests that you might be getting confused about inheritance.  The `Note.name` and the `Todo.name` fields are *completely separate*: you cannot override a *field* in a subclass, only methods.

Comment: Regarding the FYI, I understand that fields are not accessable, unless `public` and even then they might be `public final` so only read access.

Comment: Accessibility and inheritance are two different things.  The `Todo` class has _two different_ fields named `name`, as written currently.

Comment: @Knownasilya It's not that they're not accessible, you'll actually have two separate fields called `name`. You could do it with `protected`, `public` and non-final fields too and it can cause a hell of a confusion. See more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)

Comment: I understand, but in this case the `name` field of the `Note` class is `private` and is not available/accessable to `Todo`. I get what your point is though :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call a superclass constructor explicitly. And it is not necessary to have a super() or super(arguments) call in a subclass constructor. If you do not specify that, the compiler will automatically add a call to the no-arguments superclass constructor.

If the superclass does not have a no-arguments constructor, then you must explicitly call super(arguments) in each subclass constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why both case print out Note and Todo is that you create using operator new always instance of class `Todo`. If you have wrote

```
Note note = new Note();
Note todo = new Todo();
```

Then result would be:

```
Note
Note
Todo
```

The cause of that behavior is [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

To answer why constructor must call super constructor to create itself is easy to picture. As it use the elements of that super class that class must be created first, so the class that inherit it can operate on it.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the parent's constructor doesn't do anything with the object.

Generally, a constructor does some construction of the object by setting fields.  These fields are known to the constructor of the that class and might not be settable or accessible in another class and you would wouldn't want to duplicate all that code in every sub-class (that is already in the parent class) just so the parent fields are set correctly.

So it makes sense for each class to initialise the fields it knows about and not depend on the behaviour of sub-class to much to behave correctly. This allows you to change one class without having to change it's sub classes. e.g. adding or changing a field.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it does. The *super()* call is automatically added even if you don't write it. It is the first instruction in Todo's constructor.

To test this yourself, just create a new Note constructor with a parameter and delete the empty one. See what happens now:)

Why does this happens? Well, it's simple: because this is how it's implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) says it all:

> If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor,
>   the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument
>   constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a
>   no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object
>   does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass,
>   there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's just how it is! :)

To me it all make sense because the main reason you write your code in Object Oriented Programming paradigm is to reuse existing code.

There are many ways you can reuse, one of them is to inherit a class (ie: creating a subclass).

When you inherit a class, then you also inherit how that class is created.

In my opinion Java will be a much more confusing language if such behavior doesn't exist